# Trigger a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to trigger a dialog modal-message script inside a yes-no logic.
Currently it works in a `onclick` event. Example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

I want this to execute automatically (without any click) if my logic is true.

Example:

if Logic is true Then Execute

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: do you want to run it on page load? or on some other event?

Comment: Just make that a function and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

```
<script>
var myFunc = $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
           }
       }
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    // Edit after comments
    $(document).on('some-selector', 'some-event', function() {
        if (/* your logic is true */) {
            myFunc();
        }
    }
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
   }
  });

  if ( condition ) 
     $( "#dialog-message").dialog('open');
});
</script>
```

That's how you can call it with a condition.

Comment: Isn't that initialising a new dialog? I mean, without any properties set.